Flutter: Constrained Row should clip the child text on TextOverflow, but be as small as possible if there's no overflow
I want to build a Row in flutter with a maximum width of 200. The row should be as small as possible (only 100 pixels wide if that's enough to fit the content).
If a text widget inside the row is longer than 200px, I want the text to be clipped.
The problem is, that in order for the TextOverflow.clip to work, I have to put the Text inside of a Flexible/Expanded (or not?). This is causing the Textwidget to expand, so it always reaches the 200 px constraint, even if the text is shorter than that.
How can i get the Text inside the row to be as narrow as possible and still clip the text if it's not possible to fit it in the constraints?
Here is a pretty minimalistic code:
return ConstrainedBox(
          constraints: BoxConstraints(maxWidth: 250),
          child: Row(
            children: [
              Icon(
                Icons.square,
              ),
              SizedBox(width: 10.w),
              Flexible(
                child: Text(
                  "Some potentially long text",
                  overflow: TextOverflow.fade,
                  softWrap: false,
                  maxLines: 1,
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        );

Thanks in advance!

The constrainedBox and overflow works fine when you apply directly to text.
You can also practice flutter widgets using buttons and sliders with Vidution. It is an interactive UI design tool for flutter.
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class OverflowPractice extends StatefulWidget {
  const OverflowPractice({super.key});

  @override
  State<OverflowPractice> createState() => _OverflowPracticeState();
}

class _OverflowPracticeState extends State<OverflowPractice> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.surface,
      appBar: AppBar(title: const Text('Overflow Practice'), centerTitle: true),
      body: SizedBox(
        width: 350,
        child: Row(
          children: [
            Row(
              children: [
                const Icon(Icons.square),
                const SizedBox(width: 10),
                ConstrainedBox(constraints: const BoxConstraints(maxWidth: 250), child: const Text("Some potentially long text. Very very very very very very very very very very long text.", overflow: TextOverflow.fade, softWrap: false, maxLines: 1)),
              ],
            ),
            const SizedBox(width: 10),
            const Text('Short Text'),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}


However, if you must apply constraints to a row than let me know. It is a bit tricky as you would have to apply constraints to both text and row.
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class OverflowPractice extends StatefulWidget {
  const OverflowPractice({super.key});

  @override
  State<OverflowPractice> createState() => _OverflowPracticeState();
}

class _OverflowPracticeState extends State<OverflowPractice> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.surface,
      appBar: AppBar(title: const Text('Overflow Practice'), centerTitle: true),
      body: SizedBox(
        width: 450,
        child: Row(
          children: [
            ConstrainedBox(
              constraints: const BoxConstraints(maxWidth: 350),
              child: Row(
                children: [
                  const Icon(Icons.square),
                  const SizedBox(width: 10),
                  ConstrainedBox(constraints: const BoxConstraints(maxWidth: 250), child: const Text("Some potentially long text. Very very very very very very very very very very long text.", overflow: TextOverflow.fade, softWrap: false, maxLines: 1)),
                ],
              ),
            ),
            // const SizedBox(width: 10),
            ConstrainedBox(constraints: const BoxConstraints(maxWidth: 80), child: const Text('Short Text', overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis)),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}


